# np.append not saving values in array

Tags: arrays, numpy, append

I'm writing a program that graphs the projectile motion of a thrown object. In the nested loop, I inserted a line to save the calculated values in a numpy array but whenever I print that array, only the initiated value shows up.

```
import numpy as np


v_0 = np.empty(0, dtype = float) #in m/s
theta_0 = np.empty(0, dtype = float)
t = np.arange(0, 50, .1) #time
G = -9.81 #gravity
r = 0
X = 0
Y = 0

x_val = np.array([0.0])
y_val = np.array([0.0])

for i in range(1): #will use this later for generating random values
    theta_0 = np.array([15, 20, 22, 25]) * (np.pi/180)
    v_0 = np.array([20, 24, 28, 32])
    

print("These are the angles in degrees:", theta_0 / (np.pi/180))
print("These are the initial velocities in m/s:", v_0)


for i in range(0, len(t)):
    for r in range(len(theta_0)):
        #if any(Y > 0):
        X = v_0[r] * np.cos(theta_0[r]) * t[i]
        X = np.round_(X,4)
        Y = v_0[r] * np.sin(theta_0[r]) * t[i] + 0.5 * G * (t[i])**2
        Y = np.round_(Y,4)
        np.append(x_val, X)
        np.append(y_val, Y)
            
print(x_val)
print(y_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code use:

```
x_val.append(X)
y_val.append(Y)
```

numpy sometimes is not the answer and is better to use built in functions.

Furthermore I took a look at your code and i change it a little bit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


v_0 = np.empty(0, dtype = float) #in m/s
theta_0 = np.empty(0, dtype = float)
t = np.arange(0, 50, .1) #time
G = -9.81 #gravity
r = 0
X = 0
Y = 0



for i in range(1): #will use this later for generating random values
    theta_0 = np.array([15, 20, 22, 25]) * (np.pi/180)
    v_0 = np.array([20, 24, 28, 32])
    

print("These are the angles in degrees:", theta_0 / (np.pi/180))
print("These are the initial velocities in m/s:", v_0)

x_val = np.zeros((1,len(t)*len(theta_0))) #Create an array full of zeros
y_val = np.zeros((1,len(t)*len(theta_0)))

j = 0
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    for r in range(len(theta_0)):
        #if any(Y > 0):
        X = v_0[r] * np.cos(theta_0[r]) * t[i]
        X = np.round_(X,4)
        Y = v_0[r] * np.sin(theta_0[r]) * t[i] + 0.5 * G * (t[i])**2
        Y = np.round_(Y,4)
        x_val[0,j] = X #np.append(x_val, X) - same result but better 
        y_val[0,j] = Y #np.append(y_val, Y)
        j  = j + 1
        
            


plt.plot(x_val[0,:], y_val[0,:])
plt.show()
```

So I took away your `np.append`. I suggest you avoid using it, because printing and writing data is slower than already reserving space on CPU with `np.zeros`. In your case, the time difference is not yet seen, but it will when you come to Monte Carlo integration or different kinds of big data projects and you will need to start optimizing your code.

Some things that can optimize your code is also explained here: [LINK](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimizing-your-python-code-156d4b8f4a29)

I then got this plot:
[image: I then got this plot]

Comment: `x_val.append(X)` is not supported in `numpy`. `x_val = np.append(x_val, X)` would work. Same for `y_val`

Comment: There is another issue I realized. I also produced a similar graph but there should be a separate graph drawn for each value of theta_0. Is making 4 different arrays at the end the only way to resolve this or can I still make 4 separate graphs from the same array

Comment: Use tabular before
plt.plot(x_val[0,:], y_val[0,:])
that way it's inside of the theta_0 loop.

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` is **NOT** a list append clone.  Please read the docs!  It you must iterate like this, stick with lists that you understand.

But you don't need to iterate; use whole array methods:

```
In [11]: theta_0 = np.array([15, 20, 22, 25]) * (np.pi/180)
    ...: v_0 = np.array([20, 24, 28, 32])
In [12]: t = np.arange(0, 50, .1) #time
    ...: G = -9.81 #gravity
In [13]: t = t[:,None]
In [14]: X = v_0 * np.cos(theta_0) * t
In [15]: X.shape
Out[15]: (500, 4)
In [16]: Y = v_0 * np.sin(theta_0) * t + 0.5 * G * (t)**2
In [17]: Y.shape
Out[17]: (500, 4)
```